# Unity Move UI buttons through C#

Tags: c#, ios, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I have a scene set up with 3 buttons. I want an action to occur when a button is clicked. Let say my buttons are all 100 pixels apart along the Y axis. How would I attach a panel or Canvas that is 200 pixels tall right below each button and move all other buttons and panels down 200 pixels. I only want the panel to show when the button is clicked and disappear when it is clicked again; so all the buttons will change positions along with showing or un-showing  a panel depending on when a button is clicked. For all 3 buttons. Also if anyone is going to say, No, I don't want to use a drop down for this. How would I code this in C#?

Comment: Use a drop down for this

Comment: you don't like to read the full discussion do you @MickyD

Comment: You don't like to read [ask] do you.  Here's a downvote for your impertinence

Comment: Well, you can't really blame others for not read the whole article if you didn't even have the basic typesetting done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User VerticalLayoutGroup:
[image]

You can add a VerticalLayout group component to your root canvas, and then add all three buttons and panels as the children.

Toggle the active/enable status as needed in the button click event handler, that will do.

[image]